# Reference request: Continuous Mapping Theorem

Tags: probability, probability-theory, reference-request, convergence-divergence

I'm looking for a reference (preferably, a textbook) for the Continuous Mapping Theorem, as stated in the [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_mapping_theorem). In particular, I'm interested in point 3., concerning a.s. convergence.

I've looked into the reference suggested in the Wikipedia page, namely P. Billingsley, "Convergence of Probability Measures" (1999), but it seems to me that the statement (Theorem 2.7, p. 27) concerns weak convergence only.

Any help is very welcome! Thanks!

Comment: What is the continuous mapping theorem?

Comment: @Math_QED You can check the Wikipedia link for the statement.

Comment: Almost sure convergence is trivial to prove. The other ones are the difficult ones.

Comment: @Math_QED: Yes, I agree. However, I would like to find a textbook with a statement including all kind of convergence.

Comment: I think this should be in all serious probability/measure theoretic references. Maybe check Cohn's measure theory.

Comment: @Math_QED: Thanks, I'll look into it.

Answer (score 0):

Almost sure convergence is trivial.

Note that $$\{\omega\mid X_n(\omega) \to X(\omega)\} \subset \{\omega \mid g(X_n(\omega)) \to g(X(\omega))\}$$

where $X_n,X$ are random variables and $g$ is continuous. Then, take probabilities of both sides of the inequality.